# On the naturality of the definition of a deformation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series, definition, deformation-theory

Let $(A,\mu_0)$ be an associative unital $k$-algebra over a field $k$. A formal deformation of $(A,\mu_0)$ is sometimes defined as a $k[[t]]$-bilinear map $\mu: A[[t]]\times A[[t]]\rightarrow A[[t]]$ such that on $A\subset A[[t]]$ the map $\mu$ is of the form

$$\mu(a,b)=\mu_0(a,b)+\sum_{i\geq 1}\mu_i(a,b)t^i,$$ where for $i\geq 1$, the $\mu_i:A\times A\rightarrow A$ are $k$-bilinear maps.

So far and at first sight, this definition of a deformation of an algebra seems natural to me. We have different multiplications $\mu_i$ on the same underlying vector space $A$, and record these multiplications as a power series. At second sight, I would have expected that one requires that all $\mu_i$'s are associative and unital.

**1.Question**

- Why is this usually not done?

Furthermore, I see that this definition is too broad: So far, we just have different multiplications on the same underlying vector space, but we want to somehow capture that they are near to each other, i.e. deformations of $\mu_0$.

It seems that in the literarure on the algebraic deformation theory of associative algebras, this notion of "nearness" is implemented by requiring that the map $\mu$ itself is associative. I am wondering:

**2. Question**

- Why is this condition natural? Does it implement a notion of the $\mu_i$ being close to each other?

Comment: The $\mu_i$ are not different multiplications, they are all different Taylor series coefficients of a single multiplication $\mu$. This definition is supposed to capture the idea of an infinitesimal perturbation of $\mu_0$, where the infinitesimal parameter is $t$.

Comment: Typo? :  Just before the formula for $\mu(a,b)$ you indicated that the arguments $a$ and $b$ are in $A[[t]]$. So the same should hold for $\mu_i$ as well. But just after the formula, you indicated that  each $\mu_i$ takes arguments only from $A$. I think the former is right and the latter a typo.  And on the right side of the formula, $\mu_0$ should be $\mu_0(a,b)$.

Comment: As Qiaochu said, only $\mu$ and $\mu_0$ are expected to be associative and unital. But, in view of the formula for $\mu$ in terms of the $\mu_i$'s, associativity of $\mu$ will imply some equations about the $\mu_i$'s. Unfortunately, those equations are a bit more complicated than just associativity.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Your second point is correct, the first one not, I believe. The arguments $a,b$ are in $A\subset A[[t]]$. See for instance page 21 of Gerstenhaber's *Algebraic Cohomology and Deformation Theory*.

Comment: @Margaret You're right. I had overlooked the phrase "on $A\subset A\times A$".